# Operations inside variable bookmark = [(1).times {puts "<||>"}]

Tags: ruby, variables, operation

```
bookmark = [(10).times {print "<||>"}]

puts "\n#{bookmark}"
```

This is what I can see when printing this variable.

```
$
<||><||><||><||><||><||><||><||><||><||>

[10]
```

How could I do that this will be printing the correct operation inside of the variable bookmark

Edited: Let's change the number of times to 10. I will like to be able to use the result of that variable any time that I recall it

Thank you.

Comment: What is your expected output exactly?

Comment: I will like to use this variable inside of a script any time that I want.

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you give an example of what you want it to say when you `puts "#{bookmark}"`. Right now it's not clear what you are expecting. Edit your question and give examples so it is 100% clear what you want.

Comment: Edited, sunny day in...Spain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're doing when you do this:

```
bookmark = [(10).times {print "<||>"}]
puts "\n#{bookmark}"
```

Is you are creating a variable named `bookmark`. Then you are setting it to an array, with one element. Te element is: `(10).times {print "<||>"}`. What that does is take the integer 10, and then loops 10 times and prints `<||>`. It then returns itself which is the integer 10. If you want an array with ten values, each of them being `"<||>"`, then you need to do something a little bit different.

You can multiply arrays by an integer to increase the amount of the elements you multiplied.

`bookmark = ["<||>"] * 10` will set `bookmark` to `["<||>", "<||>", "<||>", "<||>", "<||>", "<||>", "<||>", "<||>", "<||>", "<||>"]`. If when you `puts "#{bookmark}"` you want each of those elements to be on it's own line, you shouldn't add a newline in front (`\n`), but you can join the array to form a string, and you can separate each element with a newline: `puts bookmark.join("\n")`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, almost the result expected, just one thing how to take out the commas so that it won't be spaces in betwen of each of the repetitions?

Comment: Can you give me an example output? I don't understand.

Comment: Hi yes, so the result as with bookmark = ["<||>"] * 10 is <||>", "<||>", "<||>" with commas and how could I do it that there wont be commas like this : <||><||><||><||><||><||><||><||><||><||>

Comment: You only see commas because it is an array, but the commas aren't actually there. If you `puts bookmark.join` then you'll get the string you're looking for!